# Problem installing Dolphin-emu, Unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies

When attempting to install Dolphin-Emu, I have come across a un-met dependences that are preventing the installation. I installed Dolphin-Emu as a PPA, so I could manually install the package. Every time I attempt to install, this is the code that I am using, and the message I get.

```
$ sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    dolphin-emu : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any and all help would be appriciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any luck searching the web? 

Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035310/ubuntu-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Comment: I've used the following tutorial to attempt to fix the issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Comment: Did you try the `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` steps? This looks like it is recommended from the online install guide as well.

Comment: I did the `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and I have the following packages being held back `libatomic1 libgfortran3 libgomp1 libitm1 libquadmath0 libstdc++6  libstdc++6:i386 libtsan0`

Comment: Hmmm, seems odd. Try also the `apt-get clean` and `apt-get autoclean` commands. Usually between `update`, `upgrade`, and `clean` and `autoclean` things just work.

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you running? Do `cat /etc/lsb-release` and paste the output in your post.

Comment: You can also try `sudo apt-get -f install`, as suggested [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa), also good reading for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [install guide](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Installing_Dolphin) available online, the following should work:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dolphin-emu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu-master
```

You could also try a `sudo apt-get upgrade` immediately after the `update` command (these two are usually good commands to try when apt is misbehaving/having trouble on ubuntu).

**UPDATE:** also according to the dolphin install guide, if running ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04, run these commands first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dolphin-emu/gcc-for-dolphin
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you try something else, try to follow the instruction from previous answer ppa, it said:

```
Unofficial builds for Dolphin Wii/Gamecube Emulator.

Install the dolphin-emu package for the latest stable release of Dolphin.

Install the dolphin-emu-master package for weekly builds that include the latest upstream changes from git.

The dolphin-emu-triforce package will allow you play Triforce games, as well Wii/Gamecube games. It's based on the old Triforce fork (4.0-315).

You'll need to enable the Universe repo before install Dolphin.

For Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 users: dolphin-emu-master needs an updated libstdc++6 (>=4.9), so install this PPA first:
https://launchpad.net/~dolphin-emu/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-for-dolphin
It will update libstdc++6 in your system to version 4.9.2, so be careful.

If you found a problem to update libstdc++6, use this PPA instead:

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test

THERE'S NO 32-bit (i386) BUILDS ANYMORE: https://dolphin-emu.org/blog/2014/05/19/obituary-32bit/

ARMv8/AArch64/arm64 packages now ;)
```

so if you have problem with libstdc++6 try :

1. heed the warning then add ppa using `add-apt-repository` from https://launchpad.net/~dolphin-emu/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-for-dolphin
2. do `sudo apt-get update`
3. do `sodo apt-get upgrade`

then try to install it again, if that doesn't works try:

1. add ppa from https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test
2. then do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

then try to install dolphin-emu again. but, as readme said, this will update libstdc++6 to version 4.9.2 so it is up to you.